# Ошибка sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Tags: python, pyrogram

```
import time
import utils
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import types
from pyrogram.raw import functions
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait
from collections import namedtuple

USER = namedtuple('User', ['username', 'name', 'about'])
app = Client("my_bot")
target = input('username чата без "@": ')  # Целевой канал/супергруппа
users = []  # Список, который будет содержать всех пользователей целевого чата
limit = 1000000  # Количество пользователей, которые нужно получить для каждого вызова API
offset = 0  # Смещение начинается с 0

app.start()

while True:
    try:
        participants = app.send(
            functions.channels.GetParticipants(
                channel=app.resolve_peer(target),
                filter=types.ChannelParticipantsSearch(""),  # Фильтровать по пустой строке (искать все)
                offset=offset,
                limit=limit,
                hash=0
            )
        )
    except FloodWait as e:
        # Очень большие каналы вызовут FloodWait.
        # Когда это произойдет, подождите X секунд, прежде чем продолжить
        time.sleep(e.x)
        continue

    if not participants.participants:
        break  # Участников больше не осталось

    for i in participants.users:
        full_user = app.send(
            functions.users.GetFullUser(
                app.resolve_peer(i.id)
            )
        )
        username = full_user.user.username
        identifier = f'@{username}' if username else full_user.user.id
        users.append(USER(identifier, full_user.user.first_name, full_user.about))
        time.sleep(1)
    offset += limit
utils.dump_data(users)
app.stop()
```

вот такой код для изъятия инфы о пользователей нашел на гитхабе [репозиторий](https://github.com/ypankovych/telegram-bio-parser)
но когда запускаю выдает ошибку как sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
что делать не знаю

Comment: Это значит что у вас скорее всего где то открыт файл с базой данных SQLite. Возможно вы настроили подключение в IDE в панели справа. Соединение с БД нужно закрыть перед запуском.

Comment: @МихаилРебров но дело в том что в репозиторий и намека на sqlite3 нету

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки

Comment: @SvatoyDyavol, по всей видимости это не так

Comment: покажите stacktrace и посмотрите кто именно тянет за собой эту зависимость

Comment: Если посмотреть кто где,  то видно что это pyrogram виноват. Он [хранит данные сессии в sqlite](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/storage-engines)